# Oracle Lob segment does not belong to a specific table or does not have table

Tags: oracle

I've been trying to locate the table that belongs to a specific big lob segment. However, the results always specify that this lob segment does not belong to any table (no rows selected)

```
SQL> select owner, table_name, column_name 
  2  from dba_lobs 
  3  where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000551103C00007$$';
no rows selected
```

Is there any way to find the table that where the lob belongs?

Comment: [Possibly related?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374462/266304)

Answer (score 1):

The LOB segment might have been orphaned. When a LOB column is set `unused`, it is cleaned up from the `dba_lobs` view, but it can still be seen in `dba_objects` and `dba_segments`.

Use the following query to find the details the LOB segment.

```
select u.name, o.name TABLENAME, decode(bitand(c.property, 1), 1, ac.name, c.name) as column_name
from sys.obj$ o, sys.col$ c, sys.attrcol$ ac,sys.lob$ l,sys.obj$ lo,sys.obj$ io,
sys.user$ u,sys.ts$ ts
where o.owner# = u.user#
and o.obj# = c.obj#
and c.obj# = l.obj# and c.intcol# = l.intcol#
and l.lobj# = lo.obj# and l.ind# = io.obj# and l.ts# = ts.ts# and c.obj# =
ac.obj#(+)
and c.intcol# = ac.intcol#(+) and lo.name ='SYS_LOB0000551103C00007$$';
```

Or, LOB segment might belong to a dropped table residing in the recycle bin. You can use the same query to find the table.